# Show popup after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I created a jQuery popup by following an online tutorial.

I want to show this popup after page load/after page load it appears + how to code it as like it appears after 5 second of page load.

Due to my low knowledge on jQuery I am not able to make it work as of my requirements.

Any idea how to do it?

```js
function PopUp(){
    document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display="none"; 
}
```

```css
#ac-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.6);
    z-index: 1001;
}

#popup {
    width: 555px;
    height: 375px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 5px solid #000;
    border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #64686e 0px 0px 3px 3px;
    position: relative;
    top: 150px; left: 375px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ac-wrapper">
    <div id="popup">
        <center>
            <h2>Popup Content Here</h2>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp()" />
        </center>
    </div>
</div>

<p>Page Content Here......</p>
```

Comment: Use the [Jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) one, this has a [setting](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-autoOpen) that will do all this for you.

Comment: put your code in $(document).ready() function and remove the onclick from input textbox.. check my answer

Comment: The "http://uposonghar.com/popup.html" is a phishing link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the DOM is finished loading you can add your code in the `$(document).ready()` function.

Remove the onclick from here:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp()" />
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
      PopUp();
   },5000); // 5000 to load it after 5 seconds from page load
});
```

Comment: Missing a bracket "(" after `setTimeout`. Should be `setTimeout( function(){ PopUp(); }, 5000);` 

I tried to edit, but can't edit with only one character.

Comment: can plz help me for how to dismiss popup window html loading when page loads

Comment: why my modal popup window loading when page loads

Answer (score 6):

try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PopUp(hideOrshow) {
    if (hideOrshow == 'hide') document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').style.display = "none";
    else document.getElementById('ac-wrapper').removeAttribute('style');
}
window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        PopUp('show');
    }, 5000);
}
</script>
```

and your html

```
<div id="ac-wrapper" style='display:none'>
    <div id="popup">
        <center>
             <h2>Popup Content Here</h2>    
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onClick="PopUp('hide')" />
        </center>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo <kbd>[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M5PXE/2/)</kbd>

Comment: why my modal popup window loading when page loads

Comment: @user94 , because the question asked for modal to show when page loads. removing the `window.onload` part should prevent it from loading on page load.

Comment: thankyou..i have one more issue.. iam using slick silder vertical and i add a read more button in that.. but its not working

Answer (score 1):

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
         setTimeout(PopUp(),5000); // invoke Popup function after 5 seconds 
  });
   </script>
```

Comment: why my modal popup window loading when page loads

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code to display pop-up box on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var id = '#dialog';
  var maskHeight = $(document).height();
  var maskWidth = $(window).width();
  $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight}); 
  $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
  $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.9); 
        var winH = $(window).height();
  var winW = $(window).width();
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
  $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);
     $(id).fadeIn(2000);  
     $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#mask').hide();
  $('.window').hide();
     });  
     $('#mask').click(function () {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.window').hide();
 });  
 
});

<div class="maintext">
<h2> Main text goes here...</h2>
</div>
<div id="boxes">
<div style="top: 50%; left: 50%; display: none;" id="dialog" class="window"> 
<div id="san">
<a href="#" class="close agree"><img src="close-icon.png" width="25" style="float:right; margin-right: -25px; margin-top: -20px;"></a>
<img src="san-web-corner.png" width="450">
</div>
</div>
<div style="width: 2478px; font-size: 32pt; color:white; height: 1202px; display: none; opacity: 0.4;" id="mask"></div>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            setTimeout(function(){ alert(" //show popup"); }, 5000); 
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this much easier with a plugin called [jQuery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/). All you have to do is add the script tag and the style sheet they provide in your page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-
confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-
confirm/3.3.0/jquery-confirm.min.js"></script>
```

And then an example of calling the alert box is:

```
   <script>
        $.alert({
    title: 'Alert!',
    content: 'Simple alert!',
     });
```

Comment: why my modal popup window loading when page loads

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use jquery, use this:

```
<script>
 // without jquery
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
 setTimeout(function() {
  // run your open popup function after 5 sec = 5000
  PopUp();
 }, 5000)
});
</script>
```

OR With jquery

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
   // open popup after 5 seconds
   PopUp();
  },5000);  
 });
</script>
```