# trigger function on page load, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a page and I want to run a function called "toggle_visibility" on page load. This is what I have so far and it's not quite doing the job, how can I improve this? No jQuery, please. This is the on load trigger:

```
function toggletrigger() {
    toggle_visibility;
}

window.onload = toggletrigger;
```

and this is the function that I want to run on page load:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);

    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: You are never calling the toggle_visibility function in your toggletrigger function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707236/show-popup-after-page-load

i have found the answer here ! thank you

Answer (score 1):

toggle_visibility function need a parameter but you are not passing parameter while calling this function.