# Chrome Extension alert or message when a page is reloaded or opened

Tags: javascript

I need to create a java-script that opens a notification or alert at the top of the screen (below the popup) that shows a form(text) every time a page is opened or reloaded. How can i do that?

```
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( function () {
       if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
          alert('Hello, World!'); 
  }
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show popup after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707236/show-popup-after-page-load)